# Python MariaDB pip install failed, missing mariadb_config

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pip, mariadb

I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3. I am trying to build a connection between a maria-db and my python scripts. Therefore I have to install the mariadb package.
I have already installed:

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

But when i try:

```
pip install mariadb
```

I get following error:

```
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.0.0.tar.gz (78 kB)

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/niklas/Desktop/Stuff/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-wfnscxnz
         cwd: /tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        cfg = get_config(options)
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 49, in get_config
        cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 27, in mariadb_config
        "mariadb_config not found.\nPlease make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system, edit the configuration file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config'\noption, which should point to the mariadb_config utility.")
    OSError: mariadb_config not found.
    Please make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system, edit the configuration file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config'
    option, which should point to the mariadb_config utility.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anybody help me ?

Edit:

I have now been able to connect to the server but not with te mariadb package. (https://linuxhint.com/connect_mariadb_pymysql/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError%3A+mariadb_config+not+found

Comment: I have checked them all and they didn't help

Comment: Are you trying to install using a none default pip for your python version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install mariadb python module, you have to install a recent version of MariaDB Connector/C, minimum required version is 3.1.5, afaik Ubuntu 18.04 has 3.0.3.

An actual version of Connector/C for bionic is available on the  [MariaDB Connector/C Download Page](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.1.9/).

If you want to install it in a special directory, make sure that the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH point to bin and lib directories.

I also recommend to use a recent version of MariaDB Server, especially the very fast executemany() method will be much slower on MariaDB Server < 10.2.

Comment: Assuming you extracted the Connector/C to:  
  
`/usr/local/src/mariadb-connector/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.12-debian-buster-amd64`  
  
then you can run this command:  
  
`PATH=/usr/local/src/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.12-debian-buster-amd64/bin:$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/src/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.12-debian-buster-amd64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH pip3 install mariadb`

Answer (score 30):

Install MariaDB Connector/C, which is a dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

Use PIP to install MariaDB Connector/Python.

```
pip3 install mariadb
```

Comment: If on Centos, RHEL or related, use 
`yum install MariaDB-devel` or `dnf install MariaDB-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding with the `pip install mariadb`, try to execute the below command and install the necessary dependencies. Then after, use the pip command to install the MariaDB package.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

### macOs

```
brew install mariadb
pip install mariadb
```

This way you will have all the dependencies needed to install mariadb successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you need to install it first on your OS.
You can follow this [guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to install it properly.

Comment: I have follwed that guide and still have the same problem

Comment: You needn't install the whole MariaDB server just to have Python connect to it. The Q requires the user to install just the mariadb connector. The DB may not be on the same  server as the Python program.